# How to create the inverse of rotating a buffered image 90 degrees?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I can not for the life of me figure out how this function works in the first place let alone how to create an undo. Im trying to edit this image editing program, and I need to add an undo function for this rotate90 filter. To be clear, I know similar questiosn has been asked before and i've seen about 20 related stackoverflow questions but im just not understanding it.

```
public static void apply(ColorImage image) {
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int width = image.getWidth();


    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            Color pix = image.getPixel(x, y);
            image.setPixel(height - y - 1, x, pix);
        }
    }
}
```

the code above supposedly rotates a buffered image 90 degreees clockwise. How would I create the inverse of this function?

Comment: Least amount of (programmer) work:  call the function 3 times.   A rotate of 270° (3 x 90°) is the inverse of a rotate of 90°.  But your rotate by 90° code is flawed; you cannot do an in place rotate without a temporary copy.  And you can only do an in place rotate if the image is square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand how the rotate function is supposed to work, consider an image of the letter F, 3 pixels wide, 5 pixels high, and a 90° rotation of it:

```
\  0 1 2        \  0 1 2 3 4
 +------         +----------
0| * * *        0| * * * * *
1| *            1|     *   *
2| * *          2|         *
3| *
4| *
```

You can see the `*` pixel at (**0**,0) should map to the pixel at (4,**0**) in the rotated image; the pixel at (**1**,0) maps to the pixel at (4,**1**); the pixel at (**2**,0) to (4,**2**), ... (etc) ... finally, the pixel at (**0**,4) maps to (0,**0**)

It should be immediately obvious the first co-ordinate (the `x` of the original image) maps to the `y` co-ordinate of the rotated image.  (I've bolded those values, above).  This should explain why the `x` value appears as the `y` coordinate in the `setPixel()` call:

```
image.setPixel(???, x, pix);
```

The translation of the `y` coordinate of the original image to the `x` coordinate of the rotate image is not much more complicated.  The 0th row becomes the last column, and the last row becomes the zeroth column.  Since the original image was 5 pixels high, the rotated image becomes 5 pixels wide, and the last column is `height-1`.  As `y` increases down the original image, the corresponding column of the rotate image decreases, giving `height-1-y` for the rotated `x` column.

```
image.setPixel(height - y - 1, x, pix);
```

---

Two problems:

1) With this 3 pixel by 5 pixel image, the pixel at (0,0) maps to (4,0), which is beyond the extents of `image`; setting the colour of the pixel at that coordinate should give you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

2) If the image was square (thus avoiding the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception), you would be overwriting some pixel values of the original image with translated pixel values before the original pixel value was read.  This will corrupt your image.

There is one simple fix to both the above issues.  Create and return a new image.

---

Reversing the rotation

If the original rotation moves the pixel at (0,0) to (4,0), to reverse the rotation, you'd need to move the pixel at (4,0) to (0,0).  This could be done by in two ways:

1. adjusting the transformation of the coordinates slightly, or
2. reading from the translated pixel coordinates and writing to the non-translated pixel coordinates.

Exercise left to student.